# Why this xPath works even without using namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" version="2.15.00">
    <TXLifeResponse>
        <TransRefGUID>1543f300-0142-1000-038d-0002b387f2ab</TransRefGUID>
        <TransType tc="1122">General Requirements Result Transmittal</TransType>
        <TransExeDate>2013-11-15-05:00</TransExeDate>
        <TransExeTime>09:57:32.662-05:00</TransExeTime>
        <TransResult>
            <ResultCode tc="1">Success</ResultCode>
        </TransResult>
    </TXLifeResponse>
</TXLife>
```

and here is the `XPath`: 
    /TXLife/TXLifeResponse/TransResult/ResultCode/@tc

Wondering why this `XPath` returns value `1` even though `namespace` is not specified?

Comment: What processor are you using? Either the processor simply drops namespaces or the namespace is already bound and known to the processor.

Comment: Running using `javax.xml.xpath.*` API

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: An API is not a processor. There are several XPath processors that implement the JAXP API.

Comment: @MichaelKay How can I find out which processor is used underneath

Comment: The XPathFactory.newInstance() return an instance of XPathFactory. Display the class name of the instance that's returned.